# Pre & code format within a WordPress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having trouble when inserting code within `pre` or `code` tags in a WordPress post/page. WordPress seems to change my single and double quotes.

Referencing [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts#List_of_Related_Character_Entities), there is a difference between the `"` character (`&quot`) and the `“` and `”` characters. Also, when using the `'` (`&#39`) character in my code, it is being changed to `‘` and `’`.

So, from within a post, I may include a snippet of code like this:

```
<pre><code>
$server_name = app_config('server_name');
</code></pre>
```

And WordPress will display it as:

```
$server_name = app_config(‘server_name’);
```

Notice how it changes the single quotes.

What do I need to do in order to keep the single quotes within my code as the `'` character, and the double quotes as the `"` character?

Comment: What happens if you swap out `'` for `&#39;` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to provide an answer if someone else comes across this problem. The code was being displayed by using a shortcode, and WordPress shortcodes are "texturized" (filtered), which will change the quotes.

You have to exclude the shortcode you are using to display your code through the `no_texturize_shortcodes` filter, as [documented here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/no_texturize_shortcodes).

```
add_filter( 'no_texturize_shortcodes', 'shortcodes_to_exempt_from_wptexturize' );
function shortcodes_to_exempt_from_wptexturize( $shortcodes ) {
    $shortcodes[] = 'myshortcode';
    return $shortcodes;
}
```